How are x64 instructions decoded and what is the format of the generated uOps?
I'm looking at computer microarchitecture and understanding how CPUs work in hope to perhaps design my own CPU out of logic gates. I understand that the complex nature of x86-64 instructions having variable lengths and potentially memory operands means that, this is a multi-step, complicated process. I'm trying to learn how the 'decode' part of the front end works such as: predecoding, macro-op fusion, the simple vs complex decoders and Microcode sequencing ROM, uOp cache, and then uOp fusion.
I understand that multi-step instructions like add [rbx + rcx*4 + 0x20], rax would require an effective address calculation from the SIB byte and displacement, a load operation, an add operation and a store operation to perform this register-memory instruction but, I'm confused how the decoders decode for all of the various possible versions of add and other instructions effectively. I've also heard of MOp fusion and uOp fusion, both of which I'm confused about. I would also like to know how x86-64 instructions are fused and how that is encoded, as well as how uOps are generated and fused from a MOp and what type of encoding/format uOps may have to make this possible.
I've tried making pseudocode implementations of some basic x86-64 instruction decoding logic, however it seemed way too complex to implement practically in hardware, and it didn't explain MOp or uOp fusion or the format which uOps could have.
I've also tried looking online for sources explaining x86-64 decoding but I couldn't find any that went into close detail on decoding or uOp generation or format.
If anyone has any sources or explanations that explain how x86-64 instructions get decoded and turned into uOps I'd be very grateful, especially if I could find examples of certain types of instructions being decoded like push, which holds the operand in the opcode, or the versions of mov and add which operate in different directions, immediates and displacements, as well as, instructions like inc which uses the reg field to specify an increment instruction. Any example of a potential solution or method which Intel or AMD chips may use would be nice considering that exact details are probably secret.

The uop format varies by microarchitecture.  For example, Intel before Haswell could only track 2 inputs per uop, so adc and cmovgt eax, ecx have to be 2 uops.  After Haswell's successful use of 3-input uops for FMA, Broadwell used that for 3-input integer uops to allow single-uop adc and cmov (except when CMOV needs both CF and one of the SPAZO group, like cmovbe which is still 2 uops, since Broadwell and later avoid ever merging partial FLAGS, they just have uops read one or both parts of FLAGS when needed.)

There's also the fused domain (front-end and ROB) vs. unfused domain (scheduler and execution ports) where micro-fused load+ALU operations have to get the load uop (which includes address-generation) scheduled separately and executed on a load port.  You could design a uarch where address-generation for loads was done separately from the actual load itself, but it's more efficient to just pipeline the load unit since cache needs multiple cycles to access anyway.  Re: fusion, see What is instruction fusion in contemporary x86 processors?

MOp is an AMD term: macro-op emphasizes that they typically decode the same x86 instruction to fewer ops than Intel, especially in the old days before Intel did micro-fusion.  (AMD doesn't call it micro-fusion, they just have always decoded add reg, mem to a single m-op that needs to get sent to both a load unit, and an ALU when the load result is ready.  Maybe they call it a uop at this stage, IDK.)

As for how you'd actually build gates that decode x86 machine code, maybe look at software logic for a disassembler or emulator that has to pick apart various instruction formats, like reg number from the low 3 bits of the opcode byte, or from the ModRM/SIB bytes.  (Or for vpblendvb, from an immediate byte!)  In hardware you presumably have different decoders in parallel, with a muxer to select the one that's correct for the opcode and ModRM.mode bits (and the ModRM escape code that signals a SIB byte...)

Agner Fog's microbenchmarking of uop-cache effects (https://agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#page=125) give some hints at how Intel's uop cache stores immediates and displacements (at least in the uop cache, although a compact format for the ROB is also valuable.)  And from the fact that indexed addressing-modes have to be un-laminated in some cases on SnB-family.  Micro fusion and addressing modes

Some RE on the Intel's ucode has been done here. A somewhat old FPGA implementation of the x86 was discussed here. But as already pointed out, there's no standard and the x86 is way to cumbersome to be of any good to design your own CPU. MIPS and ARM are better alternatives. Especially the former, having being used by multiple computer architecture books.

@MargaretBloom: Oh yeah, good point I should have mentioned myself.  A high-performance x86 decoder is not a good first project; all other modern ISAs are much easier to decode.  Simple decoders (like in original 8086) work iteratively, one byte or disp32 / imm16 at a time.  And didn't have to deal with things like rep bsf being tzcnt and other ways of cramming in more encodings.  8086 didn't even have the 0F escape byte for the 2-byte opcode map, let alone VEX and EVEX overloading invalid encodings of other opcodes (although x86-64 64-bit mode doesn't have that either.)

And yeah, MIPS has one of the simplest machine-code formats out there.  RISC-V splits up immediate bitfields so fewer MUXes and fewer gate-delays are needed in decode, but it's less simple to keep track of where everything goes for each format, and has more different formats.  If the OP is interested in CISC decoders which have to deal with memory-source or memory-dest instructions, though, x86-64 is not that bad if you limit yourself to the simple cases and forget segmentation and prefixes.  m68k is also a cleanish CISC ISA, but it allows both operands to be memory and has pre/post-increment.
